how to add images and text in the dropdown option to a column in c1flexgrid using vb.net v 4.8 ,dropdown with only text works but not with images
the drop down option works if I take a separate c1combobox control in the winform but when I bounded the combo box to one of the column in the grid view there is no dropdown option any more
I am trying to add the dropdown option to the country column , so when I click the dropdown option it should show flag images alongside with country names and when select , selected country name only should be updated to the grid view .

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
